# How do I guarantee task order processing for a queue with multiple consumers in RabbitMQ?

Tags: nginx, hash, rabbitmq, uuid

Say I want to start friendship between A and B.

Say I want to end friendship between A and B.

Those are two tasks I want to send to a queue having multiple consumers (workers).

I want to **guarantee processing order** so, how to avoid the second task to be performed before the first?

My solution: make tasks *sticky* (tasks about A are always sent to the same consumer).

Implementation: use RabbitMQ's *exchanges* and map tasks to the available consumers.

How do I map A to its consumer? I'm thinking about nginx's ip_hash. I think I need something similar.

I don't know if it is relevant but A and B are `uuid.v4()` UUIDs.

Can you point me out to the algorithm I need to accomplish mapping, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are two options:

1. make one exchange / queue for all events and guarantee that they're gonna be inserted in proper order. Create one worker for them. This costs more on inserting data (and doesn't give you option of scalability).
2. prepare your app for such situation, e.g. when you get message destroyFriendship and friendship does not exist - save message to db containing future friendship ending. Then you can have multiple workers making and destroying friendship and do not have to care about proper order. Simply do your job, make friends and if there's row in db about ending of friendship - destroy it (or simply do not create). Of course you need to check timestamp of creation/destroying time and check if destroying time was after creation time!

Of course you can count somehow hash of A/B, but it would be IMO more costfull then preparing app. Scalling app using excahnges/queues is not really good - you're going to create more and more queues and it's going to end up in too many queues/exchanges in rabbitmq.

If you have to use solution you specified - you can for example count crc32 from A and B, and using it's value calcalate to which queue task should be send. But having multiple consumers might result wrong here - what if one of consumers is blocked somehow and other receive message with destroying friendship? Using this solution I'd say that it's dangerous to have more than 1 worker per group of A/B.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just want to be sure that tasks pertaining A are always sent to the same worker. So if I have 5 workers, I just need a mapping function that always returns the same worker ID for A. Why this approach leads to too many queues/exchanges?

Comment: Scalability. If there are too many jobs for one worker you need to add additional worker and queue/exchange (as I understand you want one worker per one queue). If there're not enough workers you need to add additional worker and queue, and additional, and additional… if you have multiple workers per queue you are adding only workers (which are very easy to scale), not queues.

Comment: If you want mapping function you can use for example crc32 modulo 5 and the result is going to be worker id. Just keep in mind that additional workers will mean also additional queues (the less the better).